# I am using html tag but the image is not displaying

Tags: php, html

```
<img src="D:/xampp/htdocs/image_app/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png" width="400" height="400">
```

I am using following code but the image is not displaying.  Please tell me what wrong with source code

Comment: <img src="D:/xampp/htdocs/image_app/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png" width="400" height="400">

Comment: Hi, you know you can edit your post to include the code snippet?
For your problem you either have a incorrect closing tag `>` instead of `/>` or the path to your image/the file type is wrong.

Comment: Load if from the root folder, check my answer and if it helps you.. mark is as accepted answer. All links for XAMP must start with "/" for it to be view able by others. The "/" link will have a physical folder of "X:/xampp/htdocs/" where X is your drive

Comment: You can must also terminate your <img> tag by adding an extra char.. "<img scr="" />, it won't make any error if you forgot that but it will produce a few warnings. The "/>" will tell the browser that the tag is complete and it have an empty body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buddy.? If u are using XAMPP why don't you try like
`http://localhost/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png`
 instead of

```
D:/xampp/htdocs/image_app/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png
```

Try like

```
<img src="http://localhost/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png" width="400" height="400" alt="pdf-logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a windows link. Try hosting your image online, or use `file://D:/xampp/htdocs/image_app/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png` but it'll be only available for you

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<img src="../xampp/htdocs/image_app/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png" width="400" height="400" alt="pdf-logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an image link on your local computer, if people will view your website.. the browser will try to locate the image on your visitors local computer.

Example. Juan create an image link pointing to his D: drive and uploaded the html to the internet. Juan can see the image since it is on his D: drive but Pedro can't see it. Pedro may even have no D: drive and if he have, the file cardekho-pdf-logo.png wont be even there.

To fix your issue since you are running XAMP. Load it from root folder or from HTDOCS

```
<img src="/image_app/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png" width="400" height="400">
```

Answer (score 0):

These are likely cause of the image not displaying

1. Ensure that the image is in the folder (in your own case images)
2. if the image exist in the folder, Ensure that the extension of the image is the same as what you specified, in you own case its png.
3. Also the folder is in your project folder

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="D:/xampp/htdocs/image_app/images/cardekho-pdf-logo.png" width="400" height="400" />
```

1. Do you have a closing tag? I added a slash so the tag is self-closing (so you don't need a seperate closing tag).
2. If possible, move the image to a folder inside the project like this

> /root_project_folder/images

Doing this will allow you to use a relative path instead of a absolute path.